# $.AJAX Post not working

Tags: jquery, mysql

I am building a simple like system for my website. The problem is that, the jquery post is not working with what it supposed to do.

There is no values inserted on the database tables and the success function is not also working..

**All database tables are already in set.**

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:like('85','17','product','1','3');" class="button like_click"><span><img src="wp-content/plugins/assets/images/icons/like-icon.png"> Like </span></a>
```

**Here is my jQuery.**

```
function like(blog_id,object_id,object_type,user_id,default_count)
{

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/wp-content/plugins/assets/like.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'object_id=' + object_id + '&user_id=' + user_id + '&type=like&blog_id=' + blog_id + '&object_type=' + object_type,
        dataType: json,
        success: function(data)
        {
             jQuery('#' + object_id + '_count').html(data.total);
             jQuery('.like_click').attr('href','javascript:unlike(\'' + blog_id + '\',\'' + object_id + '\',\'' + user_id + '\',\'' + object_type + '\',\'' + default_count + '\')');
             jQuery('.like_click span').html('<img src="/wp-content/plugins/assets/images/icons/unlike-icon.png"> Unlike');
             jQuery('.likes').html('You and <a href="#">'  + default_count + ' others</a> like this.');
        }
    });

}
```

**The `like.php`**

```
<?php
// include wordpress functions
include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
global $wpdb;
$global_likes = $wpdb->base_prefix . "global_likes";
$global_table = $wpdb->base_prefix . "global_products_table";

$object_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['object_id']);
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_id']);
$blog_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['blog_id']);
$object_type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['object_type']);
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['type']);

$check_duplicate = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT object_id FROM ".$global_likes." WHERE object_type = '" .$object_type . "' and object_id = '".$object_id."' and blog_id = '" . $blog_id . "' and user_id = '" . $user_id . "' ");
if( empty($check_duplicate->object_id) && isset($_POST['object_id']) && isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['blog_id']) && isset($_POST['object_type']) ) {

 if( $type == "like" ) {

    $wpdb->insert( 
    $global_likes, 
    array( 
        'user_id' => $user_id, 
        'blog_id' => $blog_id, 
        'object_id' => $object_id, 
        'object_type' => $object_type
    )
    );

    $add_like = "UPDATE " . $global_table . " SET likes=likes+1 WHERE products_id = '".$object_id."' and blog_id = '" . $blog_id . "'";
    $wpdb->query($add_like);

 } elseif( $type == "unlike" ) {
    $remove_like = "UPDATE " . $global_table . " SET likes=likes-1 WHERE products_id = '".$object_id."' and blog_id = '" . $blog_id . "'";
    $delete_user_like = "DELETE FROM ".$global_likes." WHERE object_type = '" .$object_type . "' and object_id = '".$object_id."' and blog_id = '" . $blog_id . "' and user_id = '" . $user_id . "'";
    $wpdb->query($remove_like);
    $wpdb->query($delete_user_like);
 }

 $sql = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT likes FROM ".$global_table." WHERE products_id = '".$object_id."' and blog_id = '" . $blog_id . "'"));

 echo json_encode(array('total' => $sql[0]['likes']));

} else {
  wp_die('Error!');
}

?>
```

Is it also possible to just post without returning any value so I can remove the below script on `like.php`.

```
 $sql = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT likes FROM ".$global_table." WHERE products_id = '".$object_id."' and blog_id = '" . $blog_id . "'"));

 echo json_encode(array('total' => $sql[0]['likes']));
```

The reason is that, I already have a function that automatically get the like counts.

Please help.

Comment: "not working" can mean a number of things that are all guesses .... use browser console to inspect request as a start point and see if it is being  made, or javascript errors are thrown. If being made..what is sent, what is returned etc. If you see 500 status then php is failing. Far too many variables right now.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: @NullPointer yes, i know.. its just for testing and developing purposes only.

Comment: this is a failing issue  `dataType: json,` should be `dataType: "json",` `json` is a string not variable

Comment: @charlietfl tried to change it and still the same.. the problem persists. The problem is that, the script is not working as what it suppose to do.. like inserting values on table, updating likes count.. all..

Comment: @Ken  ... follow simple troubleshooting outlined ... what you ask is similar to "my car won't start"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You data in your ajax method is not json yet you specify the type as json.

Edit following comments: dataType is for the expected return data but the data: object should be in key value pair notation like the example below...

```
data: { object_id: object_id, user_id: user_id, type: 'like', blog_id: blog_id, object_type: object_type }
```

Ok, as a wise man once said RTM. Turns out that either method works.

From the Jquery documentation...

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2:
>   'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a
>   query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This processing
>   can be circumvented by setting processData to false. The processing
>   might be undesirable if you wish to send an XML object to the server;
>   in this case, change the contentType option from
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded to a more appropriate MIME type.

Which means, despite the upvotes, this answer wont help solve your problem at all, it's just a syntactic alternative.

Comment: `dataType:'json'` is for response data howver syntax is incorrect and will throw error

Comment: lol, I never knew that! Does that mean a the data object can take either json or a form string? I've always used json but am interested to know if the form string also works.

Comment: @RichAndrews  yes and no.... but simplest wayy to find out is look in API  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: the data as string in OP code is perrfectly valid format, assuming no erors thrown in console

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any output from your script, just use `echo "{}";` and then don't do anything with the response in javascript. The only error i see in your code is `dataType: json`, but you have supposedly already fixed that.

If your code isn't working, add this after your ajax call to give you debugging information:

```
jQuery.ajax({...}).fail(function(){
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

Note: you should do this with a browser that offers debugging consoles, such as google chrome or firefox with firebug.

If you inspect your request and you get `500` that means your PHP is failing and you need to debug your php separately from Javascript.

If the `console.log(arguments)` says `parseError`, your php is returning extra characters and you need to find/remove the echo statement that is doing it (it may not be the same .php file) or you can change your dataType to `"text"` since you don't care what is returned anyway.